# Why this JQuery Cookie value dosen't update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I just want to set the cookie as 'es' if it's undefined. But, this code dosen't work.

```
//UELS: GLOBALS
//Set 3 globals vars

//Where you are
var masterPage   = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
//Which language you are using
//If undefined [new cookie]:
    //Set ES as default language
    if ($.cookie('lang') == undefined){
        $.cookie("lang", "es");
    }
alert($.cookie('lang'));
var masterLang   = $.cookie('lang')+"_";
//Languages' usher
var callCenter   = {};
//Caller var
var current_lang = masterLang+masterPage;
```

The alert should show 'es' but the cookie never changes. I put an alert in the condition and it showed, so the if statement works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jV5Xb/2/

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the jquery-cookie plugin?

Comment: At the end of the body I add first jqCookie, then the file with the code above and then the controller (to switch other languages). And the literals, too. I guess, that if can enter in the if statement is because recognize the cookie, so the plugin is fine, no?

Comment: If the function doesn't exist, trying to call it will return `undefined`, so you'll enter the `if`. Check the JS console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the web from XAMPP and it dosen't work fine. I try it out there and works perfectly. Didn't know why.